# Welford vs Bayes?

Tags: bayesian, frequentist, bias-variance-tradeoff

To incrementally estimate the mean and standard deviation of some data one can use an algorithm such as [Welford’s algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) or Bayesian updating by using the likelihood, a conjugate prior and combining them into a posterior (e.g., see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) for the equations used for a normal distribution with unknown mean and variance or precision). What are the advantages and disadvantages of both? When should we use one over the other? The application could be a multi-armed bandit.

Answer (score 0):

Welford's algorithm is an algorithm for efficiently computing the sample mean and variance, both of which are observed quantities in analysis.  It is used when you want to compute a sample mean or variance in a way that adds data incrementally, and it is also useful for computing the sample variance in a qay that avoids underflow error.  Contrarily, Bayes theorem is a rule for updating inferences about unknown parameters in your model.  These have different purposes --- the purpose of the first is to provide a method for computation of a known quantity that avoids underflow error, whereas the purpose of the second is to provide a substantive rule for how to make inferences about an unknown quantity.

Comment: Thanks Ben. What is unclear is that both algorithms do the same thing; they update the mean and variance. So in that sense they have the same purpose. They arrive at the same conclusion, and they do the same thing. I am trying to pinpoint when to use which one.